# How to make it such that the block system goes both ways?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I realised that there is a limitation in the blocking system.

Basically based on the codes discussed, I have made it such that when I block a user, I will not be able to see his posts in the home feed, in the detail page. I won't be able to add comments or submit anything to his post. But then I realised that the users that we blocked are still able to see my post, my detail page, and add comments/submit things to my posts. This would kind of defeat the purpose of the blocking system.

How do I make it such that from the perspective of the person that i blocked, he also cannot view my posts, comment on my post, or submit anything to my post too?

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
 email                  = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
 username               = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
 blocked_users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='blocked_by_user')
```

views.py where I tried to do the implement block functionality

```
type_of_post = TypeofPostFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude((Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_users.all()) | Q(author = request.user))).order_by('date_updated'))
```

```
if blog_post.author in user.blocked_users.all(): 
    return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:detail', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
```

```
if comment.name in comment.post.author.blocked_users.all(): 
    return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:main'))
```

views.py for block system:

```
def block_user(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    user_to_block = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user.blocked_users.add(user_to_block)
    if user_to_block == user:
        return HttpResponse("You can't block yourself")

    return redirect('account:view', user_id=user_to_block.pk)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in your **profile** view you would do this:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.user in user.blocked_users.all():
        return HttpResponse('This user blocked you') #  or something else
    else:
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'user', user})


def home(request): # view that shows all posts
    posts = BlogPost.objects.exclude(post_author__in=request.user.blocked_users.all())
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Plus for starters it would be wise to make it so that the users *cant* see *all* posts but rather only from the users they are friends with. For viewing the blocked user **posts** you would use the same logic as with the **profile**.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the related_name set to `blocked_by_user` you can filter on that basis:
In your views:

```
type_of_post = TypeofPostFilter(request.GET, queryset=BlogPost.objects.exclude((Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_users.all()) | Q(author = request.user) | Q(author_id__in=request.user.blocked_by_user.all()))).order_by('date_updated'))
```

```
if blog_post.author in user.blocked_users.all() or blog_post.author in user.blocked_by_user.all(): 
    return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:detail', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
```

```
if comment.name in comment.post.author.blocked_users.all() or comment.name in comment.post.author.blocked_by_user.all(): 
    return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:main'))
```

Comment: btw using `order_by` is highly unrecommended unless necessary because its a great performance killer

Comment: @SLDem it's from OPs question